# Plotting too slow on Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, ellipse

I am having some issues with a code I am writing, simply because it is too long to plot. What I am trying to do is for matlab to plot a series of ellipses filled with colors depending on a specific parameter.

Here is the code I am using:

```
clearvars -except data colheaders
close all
clc


data(:,15)=data(:,9)*pi/180; % Convers Column 9 (angle of rotation) in rad
data(:,16)=1196-data(:,6); % Reset the Y coordinate axis to bottom left

delta = 0 : 0.01 : 2*pi; % Converts roation angle in rad 

theta=45*pi/180; % Sample cutting angle
imax=5352; % Numbers of rows in data sheet

% Define variables for colors
beta=acos(data(1:imax,8)./data(1:imax,7));%./acos(0);
phi=atan(sin(beta).*cos(data(1:imax,15))./(sin(theta)*sin(beta).*sin(data(1:imax,15))+cos(theta)*cos(beta)))/(pi/2);
phi2=phi/2+1/2; % Set phi within 0 and 1 for colormap
gamma=atan((cos(theta)*sin(beta).*sin(data(1:imax,15))-sin(theta)*cos(beta))./...
    (sin(theta)*sin(beta).*sin(data(1:imax,15))+cos(theta)*cos(beta)))/(pi/2);
gamma2=gamma+1/2; % Set gamma between 0 and 1 for colormap
cm = colormap(jet) ; % returns the current color map

% Sort and get their index to access the color array 
[~,idx] = sort(phi);

for i=1:imax

x = data(i,7)/2 * cos(delta) * cos(data(i,15)) - data(i,8)/2 * sin(delta) * sin(data(i,15)) + data(i,5);
y = data(i,8)/2 * sin(delta) * cos(data(i,15)) + data(i,7)/2 * cos(delta) * sin(data(i,15)) + data(i,16);

colorID1 = max(1, sum(phi2(i) > [0:1/length(cm(:,1)):1]));
colorID2 = max(1, sum(gamma2(i) > [0:1/length(cm(:,1)):1])); 
ColorMap1(i,:) = cm(colorID1, :); % returns your color
ColorMap2(i,:) = cm(colorID2, :); % returns your color
hold on
% Columns (5,6) are the centre (x,y) of the ellipse
% Columns (7,8) are the major and minor axes (a,b)
% Column 9 is the rotation angle with the x axis

figure(1);
fill(x,y,ColorMap1(i,:),'EdgeColor', 'None');
title('Variation of In-plane angle \phi')
colorbar('SouthOutside')
grid on;
caxis([-90 90])
%text(data(i,5),data(i,16),[num2str(0.1*round(10*acos(0)*180*phi(i)/pi))])
figure(2);
fill(x,y,ColorMap2(i,:),'EdgeColor', 'None');
title('Variation of Out-of-plane angle \gamma')
colorbar('SouthOutside')
grid on;
caxis([-45 45])
%text(data(i,5),data(i,16),[num2str(0.1*round(10*acos(0)*180*gamma(i)/pi))])
 % Assigns angle data to each ellipse
end

axis equal;
```

Maybe someone knows how to make that it doesnt take ages to plot ( i know figure is a bad method, but I want 2 specific colormap for the 2 variables phi and gamma). 
Cheers guys

Example data you can use to run the code

```
data(:,5) = [3 ;5 ;12; 8]; % Centre location X
data(:,6) = [1; -5 ;-2; 4]; % Centre location Y
data(:,7) = [6 ;7;8;9]; % Major Axis a
data(:,8) = [2;3;3;5]; % Minor axis b

data(:,9) = [10;40;45;90]; % Angle of rotation
```

All you need to do is change imax for 4 instead of 5352 and it should work
Dorian

Comment: Please post a runnable example (all variables defined)

Comment: Plotting 2 figures 5000 times will generally take a long time.

Comment: is there a way for it to calculate everything and plot instantaneously ? I added some data you can use for 4 ellipses

Comment: First take out all the labeling stuff (`title`, `colorbar` ...etc) outside of the loop; you only need to do that once. I'm not familiar with `fill`, but a quick scan of the help doc seems to suggest it supports multiple inputs at one go, so take a look at that.

Comment: Also, indent your code properly. The loop body of a `for` should be indented by 1 tab.

Comment: But how do I tell which title is for which figure, and also the caxis are different for both images

Comment: 5000 figures? Do you want to animate something?

Comment: I have a sample of composite material which I cut with a 45 degree angle. Each fibre when cut produce an ellipse and I want to dedetermine the orientation of each and colormap so I know where the different layers are. Each sample has 52000 fibres approximately

Comment: Does anyone have a solution? 
I know the function fill is slowing it down, but I can't seem to be able to take it out of the loop because it depends on ColorMap which changes for each ellipse. 
It takes me about 10 minutes to plot one figure.